# XSLT condition css based on a date

Tags: css, xslt

Currently have the following structure:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<xsl: stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns: xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns: msxsl = "urn: schemas-microsoft-com: xslt">
                <xsl: template match = "/">
                               <table border = "1" class = "TxtRis">
                                               <Tr>
                                                               <th class = "LinkPopup"> Name </th>
                                                               <th class = "LinkPopup"> Date </th>
                                               </ Tr>
                                               <Xsl: apply-templates />
                               </ Table>
                </ Xsl: template>
                <xsl: template match = "Data / *">
                               <tr align = "center">
                                               <td width = "50%" class = "DescrBox">
                                                               <xsl: value-of select = "name" />
                                               </ Td>
                                               <td width = "50%" class = "DescrBox">
                                                               <xsl: value-of select = "date" />
                                               </ Td>
                               </ Tr>
                </ Xsl: template>
</ Xsl: stylesheet>
```

I don't want to use "DescrBox" anymore but use a class condition based on the value obtained in select = "date".

```
If date> = (getdate () + 7)-14 then
     class = "LegImg LegImgExpired6 LegImgStato"
otherwise
     class = "LegImg LegImgAtt LegImgStato"
```

---

```
.LegImg Expired6 {
    background-color: red;
}
.LegImgStato {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.LegImg {
    width: 1.4em;
    height: 1.4em;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid # 999999;
```

---

```
.LegImgAtt {
        background-color: lawngreen;
    }
    .LegImgStato {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .LegImg {
        width: 1.4em;
        height: 1.4em;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid # 999999;
```

I can't use js or php
can you help me manage the condition?

Thank you

Comment: XSLT 1.0 has no built-in method to get the current date. You need to use an extension (depending on your processor) or pass the current date as a parameter at runtime.

Comment: if I can insert a symbol in the "date" field eg. # (# 12/08/2020) can I make a condition? (if data contains # use the class "LegImg LegImgExpired6 LegImgStato"
otherwise class = "LegImg LegImgAtt LegImgStato" ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `contains()` function in `xsl:choose` instruction for this.

Comment: can you enter the code? I tried to use the code in https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_choose.asp but it doesn't work by entering contains ('#')

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including input XML, expected output and your attempted XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The contains() function returns true is the first argument contains the second.

```
<xsl:if test="contains(date,'#')" />date does contain #</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(contains(date,'#'))" />date does not contain #</xsl:if>
```

In your XSL, you can insert the result into a CSS class directly, like this:

```
<td width = "50%" class = "{contains(date,'#')}_class">
```

will result in this HTML output

```
<td width = "50%" class = "true_class">
```

or

```
<td width = "50%" class = "false_class">
```

You can then define the class names in your CSS to display however you would like them to:

```
.true_class{
background-color: red;
}
.false_class{
background-color: lawngreen;
}
```

Also, you are going to have a problem with

```
<xsl: template ... />
```

the space should be removed:

```
<xsl:template ... />
```